# SocketException (SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'sfh-api-zlkq.onrender.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7))

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, sockets

I'm trying to fetch data using API but I'm encountering the above error. Also this exception only comes up initially and once it is played it works fine. Based on my research I have tried a few things like checking the permission in manifest and cors setting on my API.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Moreover when I'm making the calls from Postman or chrome the api seems to be working fine.

I also tried using a demo API https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 from Flutter app and call was successful.

So I'm confused if problem is on my server side or app side.

One of the calls:

```
@riverpod
Future<UserModel?> getUserByToken(
    GetUserByTokenRef getUserByNumberRef, String token) async {
  try {
    var respose = await http
        .get(Uri.parse("${Constants.baseUrl}/user/getByToken"), headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    });
    var data = jsonDecode(respose.body);

    if (respose.statusCode == 200) {
      // print("returning user");
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(data["user"]);
      return user;
    } else if (respose.statusCode == 404) {
      return null;
    } else if (respose.statusCode == 500) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: data["error"]);
      return null;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: error.toString());
    // print(error);
    return null;
  }
  return null;
}
```

```
static String baseUrl = "https://sfh-api-zlkq.onrender.com";
```

Comment: Have you added your "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>" line to the debug, main, and profile folders of your Android folder? Sometimes that helps in debug. Also restarting the emulator or resetting it in AVD manager sometimes helps.

Comment: Yes, already added to all manifest files. I have also tested on both emulator and real device with sound internet connection

Comment: Download an app like pingtools and confirm you can resolve that name from the android device. Create a pure Dart test harness on your laptop to test your `http.get` from there.